# Simplify/DRY up a case statement in Scala for Twirl Templates

Tags: scala, twirl

So I'm using play Twirl templates (not within play; independent project) and I have some templates that generate some database DDLs. The following works:

```
if(config.params.showDDL.isSupplied) {
    print( BigSenseServer.config.options("dbms") match {
      case "mysql" => txt.mysql(
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dbDatabase"),
        InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName,
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dboUser"),
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dboPass"),
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dbUser"),
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dbPass")
      )
      case "pgsql" => txt.pgsql(
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dbDatabase"),
        InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName,
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dboUser"),
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dboPass"),
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dbUser"),
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dbPass")
      )
      case "mssql" => txt.mssql$.MODULE$(
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dbDatabase"),
        InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName,
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dboUser"),
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dboPass"),
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dbUser"),
        BigSenseServer.config.options("dbPass")
      )
    })

    System.exit(0)
}
```

But I have a lot of repeated statements. If I try to assign the case to a variable and use the $.MODULE$ trick, I get an error saying my variable doesn't take parameters:

```
val b = BigSenseServer.config.options("dbms") match {
      case "mysql" => txt.mysql$.MODULE$
      case "pgsql" => txt.pgsql$.MODULE$
      case "mssql" => txt.mssql$.MODULE$
}
b("string1","string2","string3","string4","string5","string6")
```

and the error:

> BigSense/src/main/scala/io/bigsense/server/BigSenseServer.scala:32: play.twirl.api.BaseScalaTemplate[T,F] with play.twirl.api.Template6[A,B,C,D,E,F,Result] does not take parameters

What's the best way to simplify this Scala code?

**EDIT: Final Solution using a combination of the answers below**

The answers below suggest creating factory classes, but I really want to avoid that since I already have the Twirl generated template object. The partially applied functions gave me a better understanding of how to achieve this. Turns out all I needed to do was to pick the `apply` methods and to eta-expand these; if necessary in combination with partial function application. The following works great:

```
  if(config.params.showDDL.isSupplied) {

    print((config.options("dbms") match {
      case "pgsql" => 
        txt.pgsql.apply _
      case "mssql" => 
        txt.mssql.apply _
      case "mysql" => 
        txt.mysql.apply(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName,
                        _:String, _:String, _:String,_:String, _:String)
    })(
        config.options("dbDatabase"),
        config.options("dboUser"),
        config.options("dboPass"),
        config.options("dbUser"),
        config.options("dbPass")
    ))

    System.exit(0)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use **eta-expansion** and **partially applied functions**.

Given a factory with some methods:

```
class Factory {
  def mysql(i: Int, s: String) = s"x: $i/$s"
  def pgsql(i: Int, s: String) = s"y: $i/$s"
  def mssql(i: Int, j: Int, s: String) = s"z: $i/$j/$s"
}
```

You can abstract over the methods like this:

```
val factory = new Factory()

// Arguments required by all factory methods
val i = 5
val s = "Hello"

Seq("mysql", "pgsql", "mssql").foreach {
  name =>

    val f = name match {
      case "mysql" =>
        // Eta-expand: Convert method into function
        factory.mysql _

      case "pgsql" =>
        factory.pgsql _

      case "mssql" =>
        // Argument for only one factory method
        val j = 10
        // Eta-expand, then apply function partially
        factory.mssql(_ :Int, j, _: String)
    }

    // Fill in common arguments into the new function
    val result = f(i, s)
    println(name + " -> " + result)
}
```

As you can see in the "mssql" case, the arguments may even differ; yet the common arguments only need to be passed once. The `foreach` loop is just to test each case, the code in the body shows how to partially apply a function.

Comment: I wanted to avoid a factory for the existing objects, but your answer did help me figure out what I wanted to achieve. Check out the edit to my original post.

Comment: You're welcome. The factory class in my answer is just to have a compile-able snipppet (no play required). Anyway your final solution implements exactly what I'd like to show - partial application of the relevant methods :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this by using **tupled()** to create tupled version of the function.

```
object X {
  def a(x : Int, y : Int, z : Int) = "A" + x + y + z
  def b(x : Int, y : Int, z : Int) = "B" + x + y + z
  def c(x : Int, y : Int, z : Int) = "C" + x + y + z
}

val selectedFunc = X.a _

selectedFunc.tupled((1, 2, 3)) //returns A123
```

More specifically, you would store your parameters in a tuple:

```
val params = (BigSenseServer.config.options("dbDatabase"), 
              InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName) //etc.
```

and then in your match statement:

```
case "mysql" => (txt.mysql _).tupled(params)
```